# Page reload in javascript not working while the list is in edit mode sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, javascript, jsom

I used the below script to reload the page after performing some operation.

```
<script>
 function pagereload() {
     window.location.href = window.location.href.split("?")[0];
    }
</script>
<input name="reload" onclick="pagereload()" type="button" value="Reload"/>
```

However while one of the lists is in edit mode and URL becomes

```
https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/ProjectSites/test/SitePages/Checkout.aspx#InplviewHash928c998b-fdf1-449e-ac91-20acfdc5fcd9=ShowInGrid%3DTrue
```

instead of

```
https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/ProjectSites/test/SitePages/Checkout.aspx.
```

I think  the `#InplviewHash928c998b-fdf1-449e-ac91-20acfdc5fcd9=ShowInGrid%3DTrue` is not allowing the page to reload

how do i get around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this done with location.reload();